# Need to create a cookie to turn off autoplay of video to returning visitors

Tags: php, cookies, joomla, vimeo-player

I need to be able to turn off autoplay on vimeo for returning visitors. I know that autoplay is a no no for some but for our first time visitors we have found that it is very helpful. But for those who frequent our site, they don't need the autoplay. Can one of you help me with that code? I am pretty sure it is a php code that could do the trick but it is above my level of expertise. Thanks in advance! My site is www.destinychurchjacksonville.com and the video is on the front page.

Answer (score 0):

**Since you are not familiar with how to use cookies, please consult the PHP documentation on cookies: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php**

Sorry, I'm not quite familiar with Vimeo, since I always use Youtube. However, I believe if you use PHP to dynamically render the iframe. Your autoplay feature will be a piece of cake.

I checked there source code of your website, I believe the iFrame src link that is in this format: http://player.vimeo.com/video/xxxxxxxxx?autoplay=1. Notice how there's a GET[] variable called autoplay in the link, you can use PHP to manipulate the link when the cookie is or is not set.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["name"])){
 $link = "http://player.vimeo.com/video/xxxxxxxxx"

} else {
 $link = "http://player.vimeo.com/video/xxxxxxxxx?autoplay=1"

}
//proceed to render iFrame with $link var.


echo "<iframe src=$link width='500' height='281' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen> </iframe>"
```

Comment: I am going to try this. Thank you. I am still learning how to set cookies but I think I may have figured it out.

Comment: I guess I am in over my head. I've been doing this crap long enough now that I should know what I am doing but I don't. Ugh. Thanks for trying to help me though, I really don't know what the hell I am doing.

Comment: JInput has cookie handling that will do some of this for you. You could look at cookie login.

Answer (score 0):

If your site has members that can sign up, it's quite recommended that you just store their preferences in the database.

If this is not what you are trying to achieve, then this should do it:

```
setcookie('autoplay', false, time() + 3600, "/");
$_COOKIE['autoplay'] = false;
```

This creates a cookie called `autoplay` that is available across the entire site directory due to the fourth argument and expires in 1 hour. Most sites for these sort of preferences save for 80 days, so you would use `time() + 6912000`.

To check for whether or not to autoplay:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['autoplay']) && $_COOKIE['autoplay'] == false) {
//Don't do autoplay
?>
```

Even better, if you REALLY want to ensure any returning visitor gets no autoplay, is to store any `IP address` that has visited your site, although this is quite restrictive as many users won't remember their first visit, or perhaps their first visit was a bounce. You can do this by creating a database table that stores all the IP Addresses that have visited your site and if the current user's IP address is in the table, disable autoplay

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM ip_addresses WHERE ip = '$ip'";
$result = $dbc->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
//Autoplay off
}
?>
```

You can read about cookies here:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Edit: In order to accomplish exactly what you want, I haven't read through the Vimeo API too be honest but as the other answer suggests that autoplay is `GET` variable and if that is correct and you can manipulate it in the url, you can do this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['autoplay']) && $_COOKIE['autoplay'] == false) {
    //No autoplay
    $link = 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/xxxxxxxxx?autoplay=0';
}
else {
    //Yes autoplay
    $link = 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/xxxxxxxxx?autoplay=1';
    //Since this visitor is new and next time will be returning, create cookie
    setcookie('autoplay', false, time() + 3600, "/");
    $_COOKIE['autoplay'] = false;
}
?>
<html>
<iframe src="<?php echo $link;?>"></iframe> 
//Here we echo out the link variable we dynamically generated above in PHP based on user preferences and give it to HTML.
```

If you want to implement the IP Address, you would do the suggested above and check if the expression `$result->num_rows == 1` is truthy.

Comment: Wow. Super impressed. Especially with the IP option. I think the 80 days would be great. Is there is maximum amount of time that you can set it to? Also, so to implement this, what do I need to do to tie this to the iframe? Just add this to my index.php

setcookie('autoplay', false, time() + 3600, "/");
$_COOKIE['autoplay'] = false;

<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['autoplay']) && $_COOKIE['autoplay'] == false) {
//Don't do autoplay
?>

How does this tie to the iframe? Thanks for helping this noob out. :)

Comment: I don't know where to put what. I feel like an idiot. I have read the tutorials both of you posted but my head is spinning. I have the iframe html within the joomla article. Not sure if I should do stuff there or within the index.php file. I tried and kept crashing everything.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in on line of html so that I can insert it directly inline?

Comment: Check the edits above. If you need any help or the edits were not good enough to explain, comment again

Comment: And no, it's not possible to make cookies forever. Also, you should note that the only real sure way to do this is to make users sign up. Cookies, IP address can all be manipulated

Comment: Valkyrie, thank you so much for holding my hand on this. I am new to cookies and have read the documentation but I am still struggling. So to actually place the cookie, where do I do that? Somewhere on the index.php page? And then do I place the if else php also on the index.php page? Then add the html just as I have it right now except change the src to <?php echo $link;?>

Comment: You place the code above (the one right after I say "you can do this:") at the top of index.php. This code checks for any cookie in place, if there is a cookie it dynamically generates a link to the video with the parameter (autoplay = 0 which is false and no autoplay). If there is no cookie, then the visitor is new and autoplay = 1 in the link and a cookie is saved as next time the user comes he/she will be returning

Comment: Yes, the only that changes in the HTML code is that you are supplying it with a dynamically generate variable we made at the top of index.php (via the if, else). <?php echo $link;?> is this dynamically generated variable.

Comment: I think I understand. So I don't have to set the cookie or is that string of php (the one right after you say "you can do this:") all that I need b/c that is placing the cookie?

Comment: I editted some code above, you can see that if (...check for cookie) else, in the "else" block I have the code setcookie('autoplay', false, time() + xxxxx, "/") and $_COOKIE['autoplay'] = false; whch is what creates the cookie

Comment: So I added the php to the index.php page but when I add: <iframe src="<?php echo $link;?>"></iframe> it doesn't seem to go grab the link for some reason.?

Comment: Is the link valid? Add a <?php echo $link;?> right after the and of if else statements and tell me what you get. Also, I don't know the exact vimeo api, but I assume that autoplay parameter in the URL is how you specify autoplay, you'd need to read more in how you can tell vimeo no/yes autoplay in the url

Comment: The urls work. It just seems that the echo command is not connecting with the link we put in the index.php. Not sure why. Is the fact that it is in an iframe have anything to do with it? Hmmm. Can't figure it out.

Comment: Oh I just copied iFrame in html because I thought that was how to display vimeo videos in HTML, if it's different than just supply the link in the correct way

Comment: You are correct, that is how to display them in iframe. But something isn't connecting between the echo within the iframe and the index.php page where the urls are.

Comment: It should work, if it doens't it means there's a problem with the HTML code or the link is incorrect. Try using your own link instead of a PHP one and see what you get, does it generate it correctly?

Comment: Yes, an html one is what I am currently using.

Comment: I am using a wysiwyg to insert the html but that shouldn't matter. It seems as if the src="<?php echo $link;?>" is not finding the code that I put in the index.php file.

Comment: Could you make a plnkr of what's happening? If you've ensured the $link is defined correctly and you are echoing out as above then I don't quite understand the problem. Really sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Here are the quick solutions with cookies, I have tested, and worked fine for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.cookie('videocookie') == null) {
        // Create expiring cookie, 2 days from now:
        $.cookie('videocookie', 'videocookie', { expires: 2, path: '/' });
    } else{
        $(".wp-video video").removeAttr("autoplay");
    }
});
```